# Loading url with # in its path using android webview

Tags: android, webview

I have a simple loadUrl() method call where i am trying to load a URL that looks like https://abcd.abc.com/#/test . When i try to load this URL in webview and see the request on charles proxy, the request does not have my path including and after # . I tried changing # to %23 but it does not work.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, fragments (the stuff after the `#`) are never sent to servers. They are used solely within the browser (or, in this case, the `WebView`). AFAIK, your URL is invalid.

Comment: I have seen that when we navigate within the page we use page#position kind of syntax but in my case the # is within the path its /#/test. Is it the same thing?

Comment: # is the symbol used on the browser to navigate to an ID in the current HTML page. That's why you see "Back to top" and it's just a #, because it goes to an ID which is in the beginning of the page.

Comment: A correct URL would be https://abcd.abc.com#test, where `test` is the ID of an element on your HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Vav,
 i believe that error is because your file is .xml. loadUrl suppose to load a .html file. Please correct me if i'm wrong